# How to check if an application has unknown sources in Android 8.0

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Is it possible to check if another app can install unknown sources?
prior to Oreo the following code worked:

```
int isUnknownAllowed = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0);
return isUnknownAllowed == 1
```

In Oreo, the permission is granted per-app as described in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#security-all), and the check is now:

```
getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()
```

But this only returns whether the current app can install packages.

Can I check if another app has this permission?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of [`canRequestPackageInstalls()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-8.0.0_r1:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java) uses the internal API `IPackageManager`, which actually takes a package name argument:

```
@Override
public boolean canRequestPackageInstalls() {
    try {
        return mPM.canRequestPackageInstalls(mContext.getPackageName(), mContext.getUserId());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw e.rethrowAsRuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Using reflection or a [modified SDK JAR](https://github.com/Reginer/aosp-android-jar), it's possible to call API directly (note: if your app targets Android 9 or later, you'll need to [bypass the hidden API restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970137/bypass-androids-hidden-api-restrictions)):

```
IPackageManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("package")).canRequestPackageInstalls("some.package.name", context.userId)
```

Unfortunately, the underlying [PackageManagerService](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-8.0.0_r1:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java;l=24843) has a check that prevents normal apps from checking other apps' install status:

```
private boolean canRequestPackageInstallsInternal(String packageName, int flags, int userId,
        boolean throwIfPermNotDeclared) {
    int callingUid = Binder.getCallingUid();
    int uid = getPackageUid(packageName, 0, userId);
    if (callingUid != uid && callingUid != Process.ROOT_UID
            && callingUid != Process.SYSTEM_UID) {
        throw new SecurityException(
                "Caller uid " + callingUid + " does not own package " + packageName);
    }
    ...
}
```

Unless your app's UID and the UID of the package name you pass match (or your app is root or a system app), you can't check other apps.

There is a workaround for this, which works best on Android 11 or later: use [Shizuku](https://shizuku.rikka.app/). Shizuku lets you call Java APIs with ADB/shell permissions, which should let you use the API:

```
IPackageManager.Stub.asInterface(SystemServiceWrapper(SystemServiceHelper.getService("package"))).canRequestPackageInstalls("some.package.name", context.userId)
```

If you need a silent/zero-interaction way to check, I don't think you can without root access.